# Dataframe search and append

Tags: python, pandas

I need to search for a value in a pandas dataframe and if I don´t find it, add it in the dataframe.

Simple, but I'm stuck on it (newbie in python)....

The dataframe just have a column named 'Value'.

```
#sort a random position
    randomico = randint(1,tamanhoRestrito)
     #if the random value does not exist in the solution I add it into solution dataframe
    if (solucao.iloc[0] == listaOrdenada.iloc[randomico]):
         solucao.loc[solucao.index.max() + 1] = [listaOrdenada.iloc[randomico]]
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Can you show your data here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve your error by adding `not` and  `.any()` to your condition:

```
if not (solucao.iloc[0] == listaOrdenada.iloc[randomico]).any():
```

Without seeing your data its a bit hard to know exactly, but this alternative may also work and make more sense code-wise.

I assume that `listaOrdenada.iloc[randomico]` is a single value.

```
if listaOrdenada.iloc[randomico] not in solucao['value'].values:
    solucao.loc[solucao.index.max() + 1, 'value'] = listaOrdenada.iloc[randomico]
```